# Multiple Else if inside if statement. Umbraco Code interpretation

Tags: razor, umbraco

How would one write this correctly?

```
@{
       if (x = y) {
           // Do something
       } else if (x = 1) {
          // Do something else
       } else if (x = 2) {
          // Do something wild
       } else {
         // Do something wildly
       }
}
```

The last **else if** and the **else** will not be interpreted as code and I cant figure where to place the extra @ tag. Can anyone help me?

Total example:

```
<h2>PAGE</h2>
    @{

        var years = Umbraco.Content(3772).Children;
        for (int i = 0; i < years.Count(); i++) {

            var page = years[i];

            if (i < 3) {
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
            } else if (i == 3) {
                <label id="lblSelect">
                    <select id="selectPointOfInterest" title="Vælg årstal" onchange="location = this.value;">
                        <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
            } else if (i < years.Count() && i > 3) {
                        <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
            } else if (i == years.Count()-1) {
                        <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found a solution myself.

Fixed **Total Example**:

```
<h2>PAGE</h2>
@{

    var years = Umbraco.Content(3772).Children;
    for (int i = 0; i < years.Count(); i++) {

        var page = years[i];

        if (i < 3) {
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        } else if (i == 3) {
            @:<label id="lblSelect">
                @:<select id="selectPointOfInterest" title="Vælg årstal" onchange="location = this.value;">
                    <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
        } else if (i < years.Count() && i > 3) {
                    <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
        } else if (i == years.Count()-1) {
                    <option value="@page.Url">@page.Name</option>
                @:</select>
            @:</label>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the example is opening some html tags withouth closing them in the same branch of the IF.

Try generating a string of your html and then printing it out, something like that:

```
else if (i == 3) 
{
    String toPrint = String.Format("<label id=\"lblSelect\"><select id=\"selectPointOfInterest\" title=\"Vælg årstal\" onchange=\"location = this.value;\"><option value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>", page.Url, page.Name);
    @Html.Raw(toPrint);
}
```